How can I get a payload with a custom tracer implementation?
I'm following this documentation. Can I get the payload by writing a custom tracer implementing org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.tracing.OpenTracer interface?
With the given sources, I couldn't find any sources to get the payload. Any guide, thoughts would be really helpful.
